# Are the parent classes always referenced by the interface not the implementation?

Tags: objective-c

Are the parent classes always referenced by the interface not the implementation?

```
@interface MyClass : ParentClass

@end

@implementation MyClass

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because the syntax is just like this.